# jQuery getJSON() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON file in folder `App_Data` . Now I want to read this file and keep it in a JS variable. This is the code I wrote but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON("~/App_Data/smartParkTotalJson.json", function(json) {
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

For now, I just want to check if its read. so I wrote this code:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("/App_Data/smartParkTotalJson.json", function (json) {
                alert("sff");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to get some alert

Comment: `~/App_Data/smartParkTotalJson.json` doesn't seems to be  a valid URL. please provide either full path or relative path. Also your function doing nothing, so what you are expecting?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "_not working._".

Comment: What is the error you get and what have you found looking up what could cause that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~` character is only valid within ASP.Net routing constructs. JS will not translate it to a valid URL. To fix this you need to either use a relative path from the root of the site:

```
$.getJSON("/App_Data/smartParkTotalJson.json", function(json) {
```

Or interpolate Razor in to your code - assuming this JS code is inside an MVC View:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Context("~/App_Data/smartParkTotalJson.json")', function (json) {
```

Also note that the `App_Data` folder is configured by default to not respond to HTTP requests. It is intended to hold app-specific information. I'd suggest creating your own folder to host this file.